# How to get the previous and next post in my Django blog?

Tags: html, django, python-2.7, templates

I know Django have get_previous_by_FOO and get_next_by_FOO methods but I don't know how to use them in my templates and views. So, please help me to make this two methods work for my project.

I'm running `Django1.7` and `Python2.7` and my app name is `blog`
Here is my corresponding files:

**blog/views.py**

```
def view_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('blog/blog_post.html',
            {
                'post':post,
            },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))



class PublishedPostMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.live()


class PostDetailView(PublishedPostMixin,DetailView):
    model = Post
```

**blog/models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True) 
    content = MarkdownField()
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at", "title"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, ** kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title) #title become the slug
        super(Post, self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ("blog:detail",(),{'slug':self.slug
                            })
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$",view_post, name="detail"),
)
```

## **Templates**

```
<p>
   {{ post.content|markdown }}
</p>
<ul class="pager">
   <li class="previous">
      <a href="{{post.get_previous_by_created_at}}">&larr; Previous Posts</a>
   </li>
   <li class="next">
      <a href="{{post.get_next_by_created_at}}">Next Posts &rarr;</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So, what happens ? are the href fields empty ?

Comment: href field getting the tilte of the next/previous post like this way http://localhost:8000/blog/current_post/next_or_previous_post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it by just introducing the url tag in the templates. Here is my modified template.

```
{% load url from future %}    
<ul class="pager">
        {% if post.get_next_by_created_at %}
            <li class="previous">
                 <a href="{% url 'blog:detail' post.get_next_by_created_at.slug %}">&larr; Previous Post</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if post.get_previous_by_created_at %}
            <li class="next">
                 <a href="{% url 'blog:detail' post.get_previous_by_created_at.slug %}">Next Post &rarr;</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: For Django 1.11 {% load url from future %} no longer needed.